# What is the meaning of android:orientation attribute in xml file as part of ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, orientation, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying  to understand what is the meaning of **android:orientation** attribute in layout xml file as part of ConstraintLayout
In The code:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
```

As far as I know, each valid attribute as a "meaning" but when changing between *horizontal* and *vertical* values nothing really change.
Don't I understand correctly the meaning  of orientation or my assumption that each attribute as a meaning is incorrect?

Comment: There is no attribute android:orientation for ConstraintLayout

Comment: @RustamSamandarov, so why does the android studio autocomplete it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Horinzontal attribute in Contraint layout]

It is actually not doing anything, it is a redundant attribute.

Comment: I thought all valid attribute does something

Comment: I have tried to implement it and see its essence but I didn't notice any actual changes. so I feel it's redundant